# Sufficient condition for a matrix to be hermitian

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in \mathcal{M_{n\times n}}(\mathbb{C})$ be a matrix.

Does $x^*Ax>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times 1}$ such that $x\neq 0_{\mathbb{C}^{n\times 1}}$ imply that $A$ is hermitian?

Please provide a proof or a counter-example accordingly.

Are positive-definite matrices defined for all matrices or just for hermitian ones?

Comment: Set $x=\left[ \begin{array}{c} i \\ 1 \end{array} \right]$. We get $x^*Ax=2-i$ which isn't even real, let alone greater than zero :(

Comment: Good point. I was too hasty to respond. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Actually, $x^*Ax\in\mathbb R$ for all $x\in\mathbb C^n$ is enough to force $A$ to be hermitian.

Given $\alpha\in\mathbb C$, we have
$$
(x+\alpha y)^*A(x+\alpha y)=x^*Ax+|\alpha|^2y^*Ay+\overline\alpha y^*Ax+\alpha x^*Ay.
$$
As the term on the left is real, we have that the right hand side equals its conjugate:
$$
x^*Ax+|\alpha|^2y^*Ay+\overline\alpha y^*Ax+\alpha x^*Ay=x^*A^*x+|\alpha|^2y^*A^*y+\alpha x^*A^*y+\overline\alpha y^*A^*x.
$$
As $x^*Ax, y^*Ay\in\mathbb R$, we have $x^*A^*x=x^*Ax$, $y^*A^*y=y^*Ay$. Then
$$
\overline\alpha y^*Ax+\alpha x^*Ay=\alpha x^*A^*y+\overline\alpha y^*A^*x.
$$
Taking $\alpha=1$, we get
$$\tag{1}
y^*Ax+x^*Ay=x^*A^*y+y^*A^*x.
$$
Taking $\alpha=i$, we get
$$\tag{2}
-y^*Ax+x^*Ay=x^*A^*y-y^*A^*x.
$$
Subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$, we get
$$
y^*Ax=y^*A^*x.
$$
As $x,y$ we arbitrary, we conclude that $A=A^*$.

Regarding your second question, there is no agreement. Some require positive-definite matrices to be hermitian, while others simply ask for $x^*Ax>0$. The two things are the same in the complex case, but not in the real one.

Comment: If $(Ax,x)=0 \forall x \in \Bbb C^n$ then $A=0$. I am searching for a proof of this statement but I couldn't find one. I remember it can be done by taking some different values for $x$, maybe taking $x=e_i$ and $x=e_i+e_j$ and one or 2 more values that I couldn't remember. Can you please help? (Note that  I mean by $e_i$ the standard basis, i.e. $e_1=(1,0, \cdots, 0)$ ...

Comment: That cannot possibly work, because it would let you do it in the real case where it is not true. The usual way is to use the Polarization Identity: $$ \langle Ax,x\rangle=\tfrac14\,\sum_{k=0}^3 i^k\langle A(x+i^ky),x+i^ky\rangle. $$

Comment: Thank you @Martin, but the method I am talking about is something that I saw before, so I think it works but it is incomplete. As you mentioned also that this never works for the reals and thats true, but in what I mentioned above, in the method I am talking about they take more value(s) of $x$ that includes complex, maybe $x=e_i + ie_j$ or something like that, and thats why it doesn't work for the reals. (I think in the reals it only give you that $A^T=A$

Comment: And I had a typo, the Polarization Identity is $$\langle Ax,y\rangle = \tfrac14\sum_{k=0}^3i^k\langle A(x+i^ky),x+i^ky\rangle.$$ Anyway, I don't know what that method is so I cannot comment. In the reals, it would give you $A^T=-A$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Why does $y^*Ax=y^*A^*x$ for arbitrary $y,x$ mean that $A^*=A$?

Comment: @ZeroPancakes: if $y^*Bx=0$ for all $x,y$, then $B=0$. This can be seen in several ways. For instance $B_{kj}=e_k^*Be_j$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x^* A x$ is real, that says $x^* A x = x^* A^* x$.

Now the polarization identity

$$ x^* A y = \frac{1}{4} \left(  (x + y)^* A (x + y) 
- (x - y)^* A (x - y) - i (x + i y)^* A (x + i y) + i (x - i y)^* A (x - i y)\right)$$

determines $x^* A y$ in terms of $z^* A z$ for some vectors $z$.
Thus if $x^* A x = x^* A^* x$ for all $x$, we also have $x^* A y = x^* A^* y$ for all $x$ and $y$, and then $A = A^*$, i.e. $A$ is hermitian.